# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 for libNDPlayer.a camera functionality

Tags: ios, swift, linker, arm64

i have a problem for architecture arm 64 for _CODE_Decoder in libNDPlayer.a(module_code.o).

[image]

Comment: in Xcode go to Build Phases -> Link Binary with libraries and the library which uses libNDPlayer

Comment: libNDPlayer link in Link Binary with libraries but still errer.

Comment: it's impossible to say anything unless you provide details on your project, what you are building etc

Comment: i'm working in UNIVIEW Camera playback/Liveview in my project and UniView sdk used in objective c and i'm working in swift to connect using bridging.